# Accessing ~/Library in Open/Save dialogs

Tags: macos

Sometimes, I want to save a file somewhere in ~/Library/. I can think of two ways to do this: either go to it in Finder and drag the folder to the dialog, or use a tool such as Default Folder to make the folder a favorite.

Is there any way to navigate to ~/Library/ within a Save dialog on Lion without using a third-party app?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### You have several options:

1. Make the `~/Library` directory permanently visible in Finder and add it to your **favorites** in the sidebar. Then you can simply click on it in the Open/Save dialog. To make the Library folder visible, type the following commands in the Terminal.

   ```
    chflags nohidden ~/Library
   ```
2. You can navigate in a bash-like manner with tab completion. In the Open/Save dialog invoke **Go to Folder...** using:

   <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.
3. You can **show hidden files** in the Open/Save dialog. This way you can navigate to your Library via a parent directory which is in your sidebar. To toggle hidden files press:

   <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

Answer (score 10):

In the Open/Save dialog, press <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> (command + shift + G), then type "`~/Library`" and press enter. This will open the Library folder and you will be able to navigate as normal with the GUI interface from there.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Kyle's answer, you could also deselect the **Save As** text box (e.g. by pressing in the list of folders, or pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>) and then press either the <kbd>~</kbd> or <kbd>/</kbd> keys and the same dialog pops up.

Answer (score 2):

From the terminal window enter the command:

chflags nohidden ~/Library

for more very useful tips:
https://gist.github.com/2260182