# Remove Startup Arduino CreateAgent on High Sierra

Tags: macos, startup

Recently this application was installed on my Mac.
Now it runs every startup. How can I stop it ?

Tries to solve:

1) search in `Login Item` of current user - Not found.

2) Not found in `/Library/StartUpItems`, `/Library/LaunchDaemons`, `/Library/LaunchAgents`

Comment: What about ~/Library/LaunchAgents and similar in the /Users/you/Library folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are instructions on the GitHub page https://github.com/arduino/arduino-create-agent for both completely uninstalling the Arduino Create Multi Platform Agent and for disabling its automatic startup.

You have asked [how to do the latter](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-create-agent#mac-osx). In brief, from the Finder:

- Click on the Go menu, and select 'Go to the Folder'
- Type ~/Library/LaunchAgents and press Enter
- Select the ArduinoCreateAgent.plist file
- Right click on the file name and select 'Move to Trash'

Alternatively, using Terminal.app, issue the command

- `launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/ArduinoCreateAgent.plist`

Using the second method of disabling automatic startup has two benefits: it retains the ability to easily re-enable it should you wish, while also allowing you the ability to start the process manually. To restore automatic startup, issue this command in Terminal:

- `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/ArduinoCreateAgent.plist`

To launch the process on a manual "at-will" basis:

- `launchctl start ~/Library/LaunchAgents/ArduinoCreateAgent`

  [note that the .plist extension is omitted when using `launchctl start`]

Answer (score 1):

The easy solution is if the application installed itself in system preferences. Select your user account and then review the startup items.

If it’s not there, you’ll need to look in the LaunchAgents and LaunchDaemons folders in your user library as well as possibly the /Library folder.

The go to short cut will help you go to ~/Library as well as /Library

- [Accessing ~/Library in Open/Save dialogs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47059/accessing-library-in-open-save-dialogs)

Comment: thank you for your reply. part a)not found in `Login Items`, part b) not located in specified ilbs. Both ways were tested before.

Comment: Ok - we can’t read your mind, so perhaps you can edit what you tried and some more details on what exactly the install process you followed was in the main post. Sorry it wasn’t the two most obvious places. Is vendor support out from whomever made Arduino CreateAgent? I’ll look forward to learning how it manages to start if it’s not in the 4 typical launch locations or system prefs. : - )

Comment: with you score- thought you can read minds :) - i'll try to find and post again

Comment: LOL - sometimes I do guess correctly. I felt pretty good chances from the post that it would be easy. No worries if it’s not @Guy.D - good edit - did you search in your home folder library? ~/Library/Launch...  with ~ being /Users/whatever/Library/... If you add StartupItems - there are 6 potential places to search - 3 in the system and 3 in the user space.

Answer (score 1):

Here in the readme you can find instructions on how to disable autostart [Arduino Plugin Github](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-create-agent).

You can find the application between the other applications of your mac

https://github.com/arduino/arduino-create-agent#mac-osx